# Error install package from custom ppa: Package is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: php, debian

I currently have Debian 11 server with Nextcloud 25. Nextcloud 25 supports PHP versions 7.4 and 8.0; Nextcloud 26 only supports PHP version 8.0+. Therefore I want to install PHP 8.0 on my Debian server, upgrade Nextcloud (+ migrate db) to Nextcloud 26 and then upgrade Debian to version 12.

I've added the sury php ppa to my /etc/apt/sources.list as described in https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt: `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ bullseye main`

I did `apt update && apt upgrade` which worked without error.

If I search for php8.0 I can find it:

```
# apt search php8.0
...
php8.0/bullseye 1:8.0.29-1+0~20230609.54+debian11~1.gbp7b07ff all
  (none)
...
```

If I try to install it, I receive this error:

```
root@nxcloud:/etc/apt# apt install php8.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package php8.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php8.0' has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: This sequence of instructions works ok for me with a vanilla Debian 11 docker image. Perhaps some configuration was changed by Nextcloud?